# Is Pearson correlation more robust to outliers than Spearman's one?

Tags: correlation, outliers, pearson-r, spearman-rho

Does the fact that Pearson's correlation does not use ranks make it more **robust to outliers** than Spearman's one ?

Comment: Is this a question from homework/a test?

Comment: No, I have datasets that contains a lot of outliers, and I am looking for the best way to measure correlation.

Comment: You might want to start with a distributional fit or transformation. "A lot of outliers" probably means one or both variables aren't normally distributed. In general, Spearmann's rank order correlation will be more robust because of it's relaxed assumptions, but will also have lower power.

Comment: "In general, Spearmann's rank order correlation will be more robust because of it's relaxed assumptions, but will also have lower power. " makes sense indeed. The fact that Spearman's one uses ranks does not change the robustness to outliers then ?